# How to close nested accordion with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two accordions nested and everything is functioning as I would like. However my last step is to have the main accordion toggle close EVERYTHING when clicked, I'm having a tough time selecting the inner accordions to close when the MAIN button is clicked again...here is the accordion with ONE inner accordion example

HTML:

```
   <!--accordion-->
            <button class="btn-reset-styles faq-accordion-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#faqCollapse"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="faqCollapse">
                Hello, how may I assist you?
                <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-angle-down d-none"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="faqCollapse">
                <div class="accordion-content accordion-content--body">


                    <!--inner accordion parent-->
                    <div id="faq-inner-accordion">
                        <!--accordion blocks-->
                        <div class="accordion-link-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" role="button"
                             aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            <!--accordion inner collapse block-->
                            <div class="accordion-link-block--inner">
                                <p>Do you offer a Prescription Assistance Program for LATUDA?</p>
                                <div class="btn-reset-styles btn-arrow-right">
                                    <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-angle-down d-none"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse" id="collapseOne" data-parent="#faq-inner-accordion">
                                <div class="inner-accordion-answer">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, fugiat!
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    //accordion btn
    $($faqAccordionBtn).on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('no-bottom-radius');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-right').toggleClass('fa-angle-down');
    });

    //accordion arrow right button inner content
    $($innerAccordionLink).on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        toggleIcon.call(this);
        $(this).find('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });

    $($innerAccordionLink).on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        toggleIcon.call(this);
    });
});
/* end doc.ready */

 //toggle arrow right / down
function toggleIcon() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-right').toggleClass('fa-angle-down');
}
```

Comment: `$faqAccordionBtn is not defined` https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/y1pvncqz/1/

Comment: You might want to add Bootstrap assets to that fiddle so your collapse methods work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone would be looking for this, in 2021 to close all accordions you just use the following (note the -1)

```
$('.yourAccordion').accordion("option", "active", -1);
```

To close all nested accordions you can use a separate class and then use the following code.

```
            jQuery('.parentAccordion, .childAccordion').accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                active: false,
                heightStyle: 'content'
                ,
                beforeActivate: function (e, ui) {
                    
                    if($(this).hasClass('parentAccordion')){
                        $('.childAccordion').accordion("option", "active", -1);
                    }
                }
               
            });
```